# Error when building Meteor App for iOS using Cordova

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, meteor

Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I am running: meteor run ios-device, and I am getting that in build-time in XCode 8.3.2, running on macOS 10.12.4, and meteor version is: 1.2.1

Any help is more than welcome, I am completely lost at this.

**Update**

Using XCode8, Toggle Build Settings -> 'No Common Blocks' , see what works.

Comment: If you found a solution, please put it **as an answer** and mark it as accepted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using XCode8, Toggle Build Settings -> 'No Common Blocks' , see what works.